# Clickable table conflicting with clickable content

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I am using `<table>` to display separate tables or "rows" of data, somewhat like the following:

```
<table data-id='1' onclick='someFunction($(this).data('id'));'>
<tr><td>row1</td><td>data</td></tr>
<tr colspan=2><a href='#' class='seemore'>see more</a></tr>
</table>

<table data-id='2' onclick='someFunction($(this).data('id'));'>
<tr><td>row2</td><td>data</td></tr>
<tr colspan=2><a href='#' class='seemore'>see more</a></tr>
</table>

<table data-id='3' onclick='someFunction($(this).data('id'));'>
<tr><td>row3</td><td>data</td></tr>
<tr colspan=2><a href='#' class='seemore'>see more</a></tr>
</table>
```

I have the entire table clickable, which is supposed to send me to another page with the data-id.
Within each table, there is a section that allows the user to click the text "see more" in order to expand the text in that cell.

My issue is that whenever I try to click "see more", it also performs the table onclick.
Is there a way to stop it from conflicting? how can I make this work?

Comment: Stop the click from bubbling up the DOM with [stopPropagation (native)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) or [stopPropagation (jQuery)](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Comment: @j08691 thats kind of what I thought, ill give it a try

Comment: @j08691 ok lol if you repost that as an answer ill accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default a click event will bubble (propagate) up the document (DOM) and any other ancestor that has a click event listener will be triggered. You allow the click on the elemt, but stop it from bubbling up, you can either use the [native JavaScript stopPropagation() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation), or [jQuery's implementation of stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) (which appears to just use the native method).